# Copy row that matches with amount and invoice number

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel workbook with two sheets named sheet1 and sheet2 sheet 1 and sheet 2 both have 3 column
A,B,C sheet 1 is filled with data in all column but in sheet 2 column "c" is empty i want a VBA code so its macthes sheet 2's column value of A & B and matches with corresponding column of sheet1 and if match found then update the column "C" in sheet2.

Update: I updated My code so what I am doing is i am matching AH column in sheet 1 "dataBase" with K column of Sheet2 "Payment_Invoice_Inward" and updating the result on AL
but i am not able to add second condition so that it macthes the value of
AE column of dataBase Sheet to Q Column of Payment_Invoice_Inward and after these two condition are met in each row then only copy and update

```
Sub UpdateW232()
Application.Visible = True
Dim w1 As Worksheet, w2 As Worksheet
Dim c As Range, FR As Long


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set w1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DataBase")
Set w2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Payment_Invoice_Inward")


For Each c In w1.Range("AH2", w1.Range("AH" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    FR = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    FR = Application.Match(c, w2.Columns("K"), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If FR <> 0 Then w2.Range("AL" & FR).value = c.Offset(, -5)
Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: Are there unique pairs (A:B) values in both worksheets? Are there unique pairs in only one sheet? If yes, in which of them? Did you try something on your own?

Answer (score 0):

You did not ask my questions...

So, try the next code, please. It is fast (also, for big ranges), working only in memory and dropping the processing result at once, but it can be faster if, at least, one of the involved sheets will have unique pairs (A:B):

```
Sub testMatchColumns()
 Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, lastR1 As Long, lastR2 As Long
 Dim arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant, i As Long, j As Long
 
 Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
 Set sh2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
 lastR1 = sh1.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
 lastR2 = sh2.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
 arr1 = sh1.Range("A2:C" & lastR1).Value
 arr2 = sh2.Range("A2:C" & lastR2).Value
 
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr2)
        If arr1(i, 1) & arr1(i, 2) = arr2(j, 1) & arr2(j, 2) Then
            arr2(j, 3) = arr1(i, 3)
        End If
    Next j
 Next i
 sh2.Range("A2:C2").Resize(UBound(arr2)).Value = arr2
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You very Much ...As i am new to VBA so i got stuck and was using application.match to achieve the same but failed ...

Comment: @anuj kumar: If so, why didn't you share your code? We could help you in making it working...  I also asked you about the unique pairs and no clarification... Anyhow, does the above code do what you need? If yes, we here when somebody answer our question, tick the left code side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. in this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works...

Comment: Your code is working but the way i need to implement is causing me issue as actual sheet's columns are not adjacent to each other and i have posted my code too please see if it can be improved. there is possibility that invoice no of two vendor might be same so i want to match at least two data two  before updating the table.

Comment: @anuj kumar: I must confess I do not understand too much from your code... Can you, please, describe (**in words**) what is to be done? It doesn't matter that the columns to be matched are adiacent or not. Which are they, please? **In each involved sheet**... It would be enough to tell me that concatenation between columns AH and xx from "sheet1" (whatever it would be) must be checked against Al and yy of "sheet2".

Comment: @anuj kumar: Still alive?